# How to put append variable inside URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I have a problem to get id. How can I get the dynamic ID ?

```
ajax ": {
"url": base_url + "certificate/get_certificate/" + 2 - > this I want to be a dynamic,
  "type": "POST"
},
```

Comment: please explain your problem clearly and show your what you've done and how its not meet your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var id = $('#id').val();
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>certificate/get_certificate',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { id: id },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id=$('#id').val(); 
ajax": {
        "url": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>certificate/get_certificate?id='+id ,
        "type": "POST"
       },
```

try any code both are same